# How to index third party urls / Backlinks on google by any python script or code?

Tags: indexing

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDiTU.png)
this script is for search console domain verified site indexing
I want to index backlinks on google in just 24 hrs.
please tell me any solution

I have tried so many method but that's not working please give me the Best way to method to index backlinks on google in minimum time